# if $f(f(x+y))=f(x^2)+f(y^2)$ then $f(x)=?$

Tags: functional-equations

if $f(f(x+y))=f(x^2)+f(y^2)$ then $f(x)=?$ for all integers ($f: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$)

I know how to solve the following problem though:
if $f(f(x+y))=f(2x)+2f(y)$ then $f(x)=?$ We can easily analyze that $f(x)$ here (in the second problem) is a linear function. And hence solve it by using the linear equation.

But, As for the main problem (the one I mentioned first) I don't know how to proceed. Should I use the quadratic equation? (my calculation says its a quadratic function)

Would be greatful if anyone could help me with this...

Thank you

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @74H54N3 Welcome to Math SE. FYI, the same functional equation, but with the domain and range limited to integers, is in the AoPS thread [Functional equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2480279p20817519).

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $y=-x$ grants $f(f(0))=2f(x^2)$. Thus $f(x^2)$ is constant for all $x$, i.e. $f$ is constant for nonnegative numbers, the range of values for $x^2$. (If your $f$ has domain $\mathbb R$ or something else, you'll need to specify to proceed further.)

Comment: Then $f(f(0))$ is twice that constant

Comment: Sorry for being an idiot and not describing whether the function domain $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Z$ or anything else... I have edited the question... The function is for all integers ($f: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$). So, the domain is $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

in this answer, $x$ and $y$ are integers.
let $y=-x$.
then $2f(x^2)=f(f(0))$
let $x=0$
then $2f(0)=f(f(0))$
Let $a=f(0)$
$f(a)=2a$
$f(f(x+y))=f(x^2)+f(y^2)=2a$
$f(f(x))=2a$
$f(2a)=f(f(a))=2a$
$f$ has only one fixed point $2f(0)$.
also, the fixed point cannot be a square or twice a square.

so the solutions $f$ must satisfy 2 conditions:

- $f(f(x))=2f(0)$
- $f(x^2)=f(0)$

$f$ cannot be a polynomial, because if it were, its second iterate is a polynomial and a constant at the same time, contradiction. in particular, $f$ cannot be linear or quadratic. also the qn mentioned another functional eqn, but the solution of one won't help with solving the other.

Comment: Okay, so there is no fixed answer for $f(x) =?$  If that's the case, what is $f(2025) =?$

Comment: $f(2025)=f(45^2)=f(0)=\frac{1}{2} f(f(2020))=1010/2=505$